# ValueChanges are not detect when a value is set to the dropdown through backend?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm using one angular form to add and edit employee details. `valueChanges.subscribe()` helps to detect the change of the respective value through the dropdown when adding a new employee.

```
    this.createEmpForm.get('employee_id').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            ...
        });
```

But in the edit mode, when going pre-populated and saving the data dropdown/input box of a specific user with some new data, a backend error occurs saying some fields are empty. The reason is that even if a data is set to the dropdown through the backend in edit mode, the `valueChanges.subscribe()` will not fire with relevant data because the dropdown is set to default without clicking the dropdown. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the data directly

```
sendToBe({employee_id: this.createEmpForm.get('employee_id').value})
```

or send the whole form (or parts)

```
const formValue = this.form.value
sendToBe(formValue)
```

or start with current value

```
this.createEmpForm.get('employee_id').valueChanges.pipe(
         startWith(this.createEmpForm.get('employee_id').value)
    ).subscribe(value => {
        ...
    });
```